# Data-Bound Checkbox "IsChecked" Property Change Not Persisting

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, checkbox

I have a bound a TreeView to a class that has a "IsChecked" property that is used in conjunction with checkboxes in the Tree View. What I need to happen is that whenever a checkbox is checked/unchecked that the related "IsChecked" property is adjusted.

Right now, when I deselect a checkbox in the Tree View, the code sets the property to false, but as the code continues and references that property again later, the property is set to "True" again. Can anyone explain why the property's new value won't change, and what a solution is?

My (failed) attempted approaches are at the bottom.

Here is the XAML as such:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=BusGrps}">
    <CheckBox Name="ChkBxEnterprise" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Programs}">
            <CheckBox Name="ChkBxBusGrp" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="ChkBxProg" Content="{Binding Path=Name}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Enabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
  </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

And this is the class:

```
<Serializable()> Public Class LvlProgram
Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Public Shared Event selectionChanged(ByVal busgrp As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal selected As System.Nullable(Of Boolean))

Private busGrpLocal As String
Private nameLocal As String
'Private camsLocal As New List(Of LvlCAM)
'Private periodsLocal As New List(Of PeriodScore)
Private camsLocal As New ObservableCollection(Of LvlCAM)
Private periodsLocal As New ObservableCollection(Of PeriodScore)
Private isCheckedLocal As Boolean = True
Private enabledLocal As Nullable(Of Boolean) = False

Public Property Enabled As Nullable(Of Boolean)
    Get
        Return enabledLocal
    End Get
    Set(value As Nullable(Of Boolean))
        enabledLocal = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property IsChecked As Boolean
    Get
        Return isCheckedLocal
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        If isCheckedLocal <> value Then
            isCheckedLocal = value
            OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked"))
            RaiseEvent selectionChanged(BusGrp, Name, value)
        End If
    End Set
End Property
...
```

I have tried the following, none of which have worked:

- I placed RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked")) in the above "Set" after the isCheckedLocal is changed. Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372769/wpf-checkbox-ischecked-property-does-not-change-according-to-binding-value).
- I created handlers for the checkboxes "Checked" and "Unchecked" attributes. The problem with this is that they would run AFTER all of my other code. Suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15480279/wpf-check-box-check-changed-handling).

**Update:**

- I've now unsuccessfully tried using OnPropertyChanged(New PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsChecked")) right after isCheckedLocal = value

  ```
  <NonSerialized()> Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler     Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

   Public Sub OnPropertyChanged(ByVal e As PropertyChangedEventArgs)
   If Not PropertyChangedEvent Is Nothing Then
   RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, e)
   End If
   End Sub
  ```

Comment: your class needs to implement INotifyPropertyChanged  , and you have to raise the property changed event on the IsChecked property, 
you do this in the setter of the property you wan't the ui to be notified of.

Comment: My class was already doing that, but I failed to show that.

Answer (score 0):

In order for INotifyPropertyChange to work you have to Raise the property change.  This is C#, but you get the idea:

```
        public DateTime MigrationDate
        {
            get { return _migrationDate; }
            set
            {
                _migrationDate = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MigrationDate");
            }
        }
```

Noticed the string is exactly the same as the property name. Then this is wired up behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Public Shared Event selectionChanged(ByVal busgrp As String, ByVal name As String, ByRef selected As System.Nullable(Of Boolean))
```

Instead of

```
Public Shared Event selectionChanged(ByVal busgrp As String, ByVal name As String, ByVal selected As System.Nullable(Of Boolean)
```